# Plugin not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, plugin

### Vendor/Work/Plugin/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Work\Plugin;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';

    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;
    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        echo '<pre>';print_r("hie");die();
        $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $delivery_details = json_decode($request_body, true);
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        $shipping_date = null;
        if (isset($delivery_details['shipping_latlng']['shipping_date'])) {
            $shipping_date = $delivery_details['shipping_latlng']['shipping_date'];
        }
        $quote->setShippingLat($shipping_date);
        $quote->save();
    }
}
```

### Vendor/Work/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
    <plugin name="save-delivery-details" type="Vendor\Work\Plugin\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Comment: Did you set your sequence in your module file         

<sequence>
     <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
     <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
</sequence>

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Interface when defining the plugin in your di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="save-delivery-details" type="Vendor\Work\Plugin\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

That's because you can't always be sure that `Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement` is the implementation

Comment: this is correct I believe that this answer could mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I made sure everything is proper like sequence, type name etc but still it wasn't working.

For my case i added the plugin inside `frontend/di.xml` which was
causing the issue. After removing the scope and adding it under
`etc/di.xml` it started working.

Hope it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the link
[Get Logged in Customer Data in Magento 2](http://www.blogtreat.com/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/)

The only difference am seeing is, used factory object instead of normal model object.